# what's the nr_slab of VM used for?

Tags: linux, performance, virtual-machine

After performance test, I found the server disk busy is over 80%. I checked CPU usage, and no wait rate found. I found the nr_slab of VM is big. What's the counter? It can cause high disk activities?

Comment: Counter nr_slabs is used for debugging purposes only, so it is quite likely not the sole or any reason for anything you might see during your performance tests. If your disks are busy, there are many other reasons for this and many things depend on what kind of hardware/virtualization you're running your performance tests on.

Comment: thanks. just curious there were no data in another test.